# ng-repeat inside an ng-transclude (directive)

Tags: angularjs

Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/HVnZWK5dNuvu180HCT6o

I thought I wrote a simple directive that just rewrites `table` elements a little. The intent is to let the transcluded body do its thing with respect to the parent scope. It's a toy, I know, but I'm trying to test drive out a "smarter" table, but I can't get past the basics.

daTable.js:

```
angular.module('daTable', [])
.directive('daTable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/da-table.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {}
  }
});
```

da-table.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" border="1">
  <caption>Table</caption>
  <thead><tr><th>column 1</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody ng-transclude></tbody>
</table>
```

main.html (a routed view through the $routeProvider)

```
...
<da-table>
  <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
    <td>{{r.col1}}</td>
    <td>{{r.col2}}</td>
    <td>{{r.col3}}</td>
  </tr>
</da-table>
...
```

main.js:

```
dataTableApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [
    {col1: "data 1,1", col2: "data 1,2", col3: "data 1,3"},
    {col1: "data 2,1", col2: "data 2,2", col3: "data 2,3"},
    {col1: "data 3,1", col2: "data 3,2", col3: "data 3,3"}
  ]
});
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail, but considering that the table structure is part of the directive too, it might make more sense to encapsulate the ng-repeat inside of it, rather than transcluding it.

Comment: That's my plan, but it shouldn't affect anything inside the transclude, should it? All the bindings should be part of the parent scope and is rendered in that scope? I did some more poking around and if I replace the tr's with anything else, the ng-repeat starts to work! There must be something magical going with table rows.

Answer (score 6):

I've been doing a lot of research in the area of directives not working properly with transclusion and ng-repeat.

I came across this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Which basically says to avoid using <table>, <td>, or <tr>'s in directives. The problem is that the content is being moved outside of the element by the browser before angular has a chance to even look at them.

They strongly recommend (in the github issue) to use a CSS based table with your directive.

Comment: Since you answered, that thread concluded with a fix. However, I can't get it to work on the author's plnkr or my own, [simpler example](http://jsfiddle.net/A2FPR/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it is really tricky issue and my vote is that this behaviour is because how browsers reorder emelents that are inside  elements. It can 'pop' elements that are not  inline with what table can contain.

And in your example ngTransclude appends transcluded content after , so order of elements becomes invalid and  elements poped out of  so are not shown.

So may be try to use other options to structure your page layout - like fluid layouts etc, that allows to avoid wierd browser's behavour with  elements.